# JSON response from swagger-server received in single quotes, robot-framework validation fails as json.loads fails

Tags: python, json, http, swagger, robotframework

I am trying to validate my swagger-server code via robot-framework.The server handler is returning a dictionary (or json object?). The robot-framework tries to validate the response, but gives this error.

**failed: JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)**

The problem is response has single-quotes instead of double-quotes (or the response is not identified as a json) so json.loads fails.

I tried adding content-type and mimetype headers as 'application/json'. Tried flask's jsonify.

Here is the part of the code that returns the response.

```
def grants_post(project, GrantRequest, Accept=None, Content_Type=None, Authorization=None):
    # code that creates a large dictionary called rsp.

    grant_uri_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    AsyncGrantResponses[grant_uri_id] = rsp
    print(rsp['output'])
    return rsp['output'], 201, {'location': "sol003/grant/" + project + "/grant/v1/grants/" + grant_uri_id , 'mimetype' : "application/json" }
```

Here is robot-framework results. After schema validation it does json.loads. Used '.......' in b/w since the data is large.

> Create a new Grant - Synchronous mode
>   | FAIL | Evaluating expression `json.loads('''{'extVirtualLinks':
>   [{'vimConnectionId': 'vimAccount',
>   'extCps':........................... 'id':
>   '718bb9a2-37dd-4238-a393-7936a8b53086'}''')` failed: JSONDecodeError:
>   Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2
>   (char 1)

I think the expected output should have double quotes instead of single quotes in the data.

Comment: The triple quotes comes from the robot-frameworks test suite.

Comment: ${result}=    Output    response body                                                            ${json}=    evaluate    json.loads('''${result}''')    json                                      Validate Json    grant.schema.json    ${json}

Comment: Yes.Then it gives this error                                                                                     'Got value `\'{"_links": {"vnfInstance":.................................'` of type `string`. Value must be of type(s): `(\'object\',)`'

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the robot test suite code, I changed this line,

```
${json} = evaluate json.loads('''${result}''') json
```

to

```
${json} = evaluate json.loads(json.dumps(${result})) json
```

Now it validates fine.